# Detecting a font in an image

Tags: typography, font-identification

I've this screenshot from an image that I had created before I moved it to a USB drive and formatted my PC. So I lost all my old fonts and that's why I want to know which font I had used in that image :

[image: my image]

So please what is that font and how can I detect fonts in images ?

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366

Comment: It looks like some kind of bitmap font, but the image is really too small to identify. Do you have something larger or with more letters?  It's really hard to identify any font with so few letters.

Comment: @BillyKerr no I don't have a bigger one, that's the issue, but maybe scaling the image would do the work, no ?

Comment: You can't scale any more information into it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - but it looks like a bitmap font anyway, so scaling with nearest neighbour might help. [See example](https://imgur.com/ZS5AGrz).

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks for doing the work! Now, we just need to identify that font

Comment: @Salem . . . so, if it looks like a bitmap font, and if you assume it is, then there are over [50 pages of bitmap fonts on Dafont](https://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php?text=Triples) which you could search through for a match. Sorry I don't have time to do this myself.

Comment: @BillyKerr, no problem, thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload a bigger version of the image to [www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
It will show you similar fonts. If it is a popular font you should find the exact font. But this seems like a badly done free font so might be tricky to find again...